# Can we promote only single flow from a single process group containing one flows in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I am trying to use NiFi registry for flow promotion from Dev to QA environment, let says I have process group named PG1, and it has flows consisting of many processes, lets say flow `f1` has processors **p1 --> p2 --> p3** and flow `f2` has processors 
**x1-->x2-->x3** now if I make changes to flow 2 i.e. **x1 --> x2--> x3 --> x4** and check it in to repository, Now all I need is only promote flow `f2` to QA environment and ignore flow `f1`.

Answer (score 3):

A process group is the unit of version control, so changes to any processors within the process group will result in a change that needs to be committed, it doesn't matter if the processors are connected or parts of independent logical flows.

If you need the version control to be more granular, then f1 and f2 should be in their own nested process groups. You can gave version control on PG1, PG2 (f1), and PG3 (f2). Then you can deploy the whole thing as PG1, but later on make updates to only the sub-groups.